# How to implement Dispose pattern in MVC Repository pattern architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern, dispose

Reading up alot on how to implement the Dispose pattern in a typical layered MVC architecture, I have come across alot of answers and even contradictions, which has now confused me.

I'm using the Domain Model pattern, and Repository pattern. Note, not using UoW, or Dependency Injection. I may use DI soon (not sure yet), which means the architecture would change and the Dispose technique also.

Anyway, here is the code.

**Controller**

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _myService.Dispose();

        // Call base class implementation
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

**Service**

```
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _myRepository.Dispose();
    }
```

**Domain**

```
public interface IMyRepository : IDisposable
```

**Repository**

Extra question: Is the IDisposable required here?

```
    public class MyRepository : IMyRepository, IDisposable


    // Flag, has Dispose already been called?
    private bool disposed = false;

    // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // Free any other managed objects here
                _context.Dispose();
            }
        }

        // Free any unmanaged objects here
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    // Public implementation of Dispose pattern callable by consumers
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Dispose of unmanaged resources
        Dispose(true);
        // Suppress finalization
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
```

I have put together (below) what I believe is correct, but not entirely sure.

**Question. Will the above code cleanup all unmanaged resources, e.g. database connections? (i.e. is what I've done correct)**

Comment: You asked a few related questions, I would recommend editing and putting the question you are most interested in getting an answer about as the last line, and in bold, and then related questions in non-bold.  Otherwise answers may choose the easiest answer and ignore others.  I would image the most important one being "Will this cleanup all unmanaged resources (database connections, etc.)?"

Comment: Thanks for the tip, updated it :)

Comment: I've just found this by chance while looking into something else, both the repository class and it's interface class have the IDisposable included. This is by a Microsoft web guy:  http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 1):

no, not on `MyRepository` as you've already inherited it though `IMyRepository`

Comment: Was unsure about this, i.e. implementing an interface doesn't just bind you to a contract to implement the methods, properties, events... in the concrete class, but also does inheritance. Thanks.